# Monitor new coming files and start a new VM

Tags: azure, alert, azure-virtual-machine, monitor

I would like to build a trigger like thing that can monitor my Azure File Storage for new coming files. If there are new files then create a VM.

What should I look at? **Monitor + Alert** or *Logic Apps Designer*?

Any one done anything similar before? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What should I look at? Monitor + Alert or Logic Apps Designer?

I recommand that you could use [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/)+ [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview).

You could use the Event Grid to listen the change of the storage and implement the creating VM in the Azure function. About how to handle Event Grid events in Azure Function, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid).

**Note:** Currently, the following Azure services support sending events to Event Grid:

> - Azure Subscriptions (management operations)
> - Container Registry
> - Custom Topics
> - Event Hubs
> - IoT Hub
> - Media Services
> - Resource Groups (management operations)
> - Service Bus
> - Storage Blob
> - **Storage General-purpose v2 (GPv2)**

If Azure blob storage is possible, you could use the Azure function with [blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function).